# MySQL - Show latest successful test

Tags: mysql

How can I get all the latest successful tests by program? The latest one has the highest **Build** number and successful are all **PASSED** and **OF CONCERN**

My table looks like this (I excluded some columns from the original):

```
+----+---------+----------------+-------+-----------+---------+
| ID | Test    |    Program     | Build |   Result  | Tester  |   
+----+---------+----------------+-------+-----------+---------+
| 1  |       1 | Mag. & Speech  | 1825  | PASSED    | Dale    |
| 2  |       2 | Scr. Reader    | 1820  | PASSED    | Aadarsh |
| 3  |       2 | Scr. Reader    | 1821  | PASSED    | Tony    |
| 4  |       2 | Scr. Reader    | 1824  | PASSED    | Tony    |
| 5  |       2 | Mag. & Speech  | 1820  | PASSED    | Colin   |
| 6  |       2 | Mag. & Speech  | 1821  | FAILED    | Dale    |
| 7  |       2 | Mag. & Speech  | 1822  | OF CONCERN| Tony    |
| 8  |       2 | Mag.           | 1820  | PASSED    | Steven  |
| 9  |       3 | Scr. Reader    | 1820  | NOT TESTED| Aadarsh |
+----+---------+----------------+-------+-----------+---------+
```

As a result I would want to get the row (**ID**) 1,4,7,8. As you can see, no program has more than one of the same test.

---

**Edit:**
Added some missing information to the table.
Sadly I don't have the queries anymore, I tried, but I didn't get very far with just *Where* and *Order By*.

Comment: Yes, I tried to order by build, filter out all succesful tests and then grouping by Test and Program.

Answer (score 2):

This query should do the trick

```
SELECT      t3.*
    FROM    (
        SELECT      t1.ID,
                    MAX(t1.Build) as Build
            FROM    table_name t1
            WHERE   LOWER(t1.Result) NOT IN( 'n/a', 'not completed', 'not tested' )
        GROUP BY    t1.Test, t1.Program
        ) t2
INNER JOIN  table_name t3
        ON  t3.ID = t2.ID
        AND t3.Build = t2.Build;
```

Unfortunately it is a bit complicated due to group by limitations.

Please replace table_name (in 2 places) with proper name

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have removed one subquery which is not needed.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I still get uncompleted tests.

Comment: What do you mean? What value of Result do you get?

Comment: Some of the given results still contain  'N/A' and 'Not Completed'.

Comment: Do you mean 'Not Completed' or 'NOT TESTED'?  Could you provide the result rows which are incorrect?

Comment: I have introduced one fix, that should deal with case issues. Does it work now?

Comment: This doesn't give me duplicated tests. I get 800 rows as result,which is also the number of existing tests. But since each test is performed on multiple programs, there has to be more than 800 rows. Also, I actually meant Not Tested and Not Completed, N/A, since all three can be the value in the column **Result**. @piotrgajow

Comment: @tuhang Ok, I have updated the answer to include new table structure and 'Not Tested' Result from updated question.